# UTF-8 encoding polish char - C#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf, polish

My program reads names containing Polish characters from an Excel file, it should convert them to UTF-8, but it gets a question mark (?) in place of the Polish letters, e.g. instead of Leśna Le?na. Below is a code snippet, I would appreciate any suggestions as to why it is not working.

```cs
List<Adress> list = new List<Adress>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
{
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        if (csv.GetField(3) == "Miasto" || csv.GetField(4) == "Ulica")
        {
            continue;
        }
        string consumerId = csv.GetField(0);
        string investmentId = csv.GetField(6);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(investmentId))
        {
            investmentId = " ";
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(consumerId))
        {
            consumerId = " ";
        }

        list.Add(new Adress
        {
            ConsumerId = consumerId,
            AccountGroup = csv.GetField(1),
            PostalCode = csv.GetField(2),
            City = csv.GetField(3),
            Street = csv.GetField(4),
            Number = csv.GetField(5),
            InvestmentId = investmentId
        });
    }

    var records = list.ToArray();
    return records;
}
```

I tried:

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8)) 
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { Encoding= Encoding.UTF8 }))
```

and

```cs
Street = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv.GetField(4))),
```

I also tried Windows-1252 encoding

```cs
string charset = detector.Charset.ToLowerInvariant();
Encoding encoding;

if (charset == "windows-1252")
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
}
```

and after everything still can't get Polish chars.

Comment: " it should convert them to UTF-8" - what *exactly* do you mean by that? What encoding is the file in to start with? How are you viewing the result?

Comment: The user in the application selects a csv file, I do not know what encoding it may have. After uploading this csv file to the application, a table is generated with values corresponding to those in the csv. There are Polish characters in the uploaded files, but after generating the data in my wpf application these characters no longer appear. I can see the results in the desktop application window.

Comment: If the input encoding is not known then you can't convert anything since you don't even read it correctly.

Comment: Oh, that's make sense, thank you. How then could I approach this problem?

Comment: @JKKK ultimately, you need to *find out* what the input encoding is; this could be by asking, this could be by trial and error - using a human to sanitize, because the problem with encodings (especially code-page encodings, like here) is that using the wrong one will give you *something*, just... not necessarily the same something that the original author intended